# Should my recent DIY question go here instead?

Tags: discussion, diy

I originally posted "[How do I get the most out of cracked lumber?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/126791/how-do-i-get-the-most-out-of-cracked-lumber)" in DIY because I hadn't noticed that Woodworking (beta) existed until after I posted the question. Now that I'm aware of this section, it seems like the question may belong here more than there.

Should the question be migrated from there to here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are good you would get more responses here.

Comment: In that case, it would be nice if a moderator would move it for me.